Moq verify property init
How do i verify an init-call with Moq? I have the following property defined in an interface:
public string Text { init; }

I want to verify that init was called with a specific parameter. Is that possible?

Wouldn't it be the same way as if it was Set?

Why would you need that when Moq is going to instantiate the object?

@gunr2171 No, as i cannot assign a value in the VerifySet-call

@IvanPetrov Good point, i need it inside of an blazor unit test, maybe i've overseen something

@IvanPetrov I've checked it. So basically i am using an parameter with initializer only in a blazor component. Now i want to verify that this parameter is set correctly on my mock instance. Is this even possibly? What would be the right approach to check this?

@Stevie you are creating the mock yourself in your tests. No other object is creating it in passing so you would need to verify how it was created. You know because you explicitly do so...I really don't understand the issue.

@IvanPetrov initializers can be changed using System.Reflection. I guess Blazor is doing exactly that - therefor i am not the one calling the initializer directly - therefor i would need moq

@IvanPetrov I've discovered that moq can actually track the invocations, there is just no interface for verifying them. Added a discussion on the moq github

@Stevie actually managed to get a solution going with some Expressions. You might try it out before there is a more official way to do it. Works with some simple tests on my end. - see answer

Since Moq relies on Action<I> setterExpression for its VerifySet, it doesn't seem possible to do that with the current API due to the init compiler errors we would get.
However, we can rely on expressions in an extension method to circumvent the compiler errors. Following a possible implementation that works upon initial testing:
public static class MoqInitExtensions {
    public static void VerifyInit<T, TPropVal>(this Mock<T> mock,
    string propertyName, TPropVal propValue)
    where T : class {
        var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property is null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"No property {propertyName} on {typeof(T).Name}");

        if (property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TPropVal)) == false)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Property {propertyName} is of type {property.PropertyType} but got a value of {typeof(TPropVal)} ");

        var propertySetter = property.SetMethod;
        if (propertySetter is null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"No setter for {propertyName} on {typeof(T).Name}");

        // OPTIONAL:
        var initOnly = propertySetter.ReturnParameter
            .GetRequiredCustomModifiers()
            .Any(mod => mod == typeof(IsExternalInit));
        if (initOnly == false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{propertyName} is not init-only. Use VerifySet instead.");
  
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, property);
        var assign = Expression.Assign(prop, Expression.Constant(propValue));
        var setterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(assign, param);
        var compiled = setterLambda.Compile();
        mock.VerifySet(compiled);
    }
}


public interface I {
    string Text { init; }
}

void Main() {
    var mock = new Mock<I>();
    var obj = mock.Object;

    // Simulate reflection call for "init" setter
    var setter = typeof(I).GetProperty("Text").SetMethod;

    string toCallWith = "hello";
    setter.Invoke(obj, [toCallWith]);

    mock.VerifyInit("Text", toCallWith); // succeeds

    try {
        mock.VerifyInit("Text", "not" + toCallWith);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        //        Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: < param > => < param >.Text = "nothello"
        //
        //Performed invocations:
        //
        //   Mock < I:1 > ():
        //
        //      I.Text = "hello"
    }
}

